# How to alter some Woocommerce admin general settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, settings, admin

I am trying to develop a plugin for Woocommerce that provides a better user signup flow. It would require the *"When creating an account, send the new user a link to set their password"* field to be disabled at all times.

I can't figure out where to hook into to set admin fields in WooCommerce. I have been staring at the docs forever, it seems like, and I can't make sense of it. I sort of followed the breadcrumbs to this page [Hooks Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html).

Where I found the following hook here [`woocommerce_admin_field_`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-admin-class-wc-admin-settings.html#source-view.720), but I am not able to use `add_filter()` with it, like:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_field_woocommerce_registration_generate_password', [Settings::class, 'setRequiredWoocommerceSettings']);
```

And I tried to do:

```
public static function setRequiredWoocommerceSettings($setting) {
    $isSendPasswordLinkActive = get_option('woocommerce_registration_generate_password');
    if ($isSendPasswordLinkActive == 'yes') {
        Utils::debug($settings);
        return 'no';
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the option using:

```php
get_option('woocommerce_registration_generate_password');
```

But I am not really sure what I need to do to make sure this field is always checked off.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will be nice if you set a personalized username, instead of "user3331344"…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right composite hook to be used is `woocommerce_get_settings_{$tab_section}`, where `$tab_section` value for "Accounts and Privacy" section is `account`.

To disable the option `woocommerce_registration_generate_username` and remove properly the related checkbox field (setting), from WooCommerce general settings "Accounts and Privacy" section tab content, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_account', 'woocommerce_general_settings_account_tab_content', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_general_settings_account_tab_content( $settings, $current_section ) {
    // The current section is an empty string as there are no additional settings sub-tab for this section
    if( $current_section === '' ) {
        // The setting field ID to target
        $option_slug = 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username'; 
        // Loop through WooCommerce general "account" settings
        foreach ( $settings as $index => $field ) {
            // Target the required specific setting
            if( $field['id'] === $option_slug ) {
                // If the option is activayed
                if ( get_option($option_slug) ==='yes' ) {
                    update_option($option_slug, 'no'); // Disable it
                }
                // Remove the field from settings
                unset($settings[$index]);
                break; // stop the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return $settings;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Then the setting will be removed, and the option set to "no":

[image]

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I have been combing through Woocommerce docs for over a day. Sometimes I feel like companies need to publish documentation on how to read their documentation.